# Slim framework can't create a class

Tags: php, slim

I have small issue in create a result class where I want to save all error messages in my app
Here is my files tree :

[image]

Here is my simple Result class:

```
class Result {
    public $errors;
    public $data;

    public function __construct($errors = array(), $data = null) {
        $this->errors = $errors;
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}
```

And here is my Home Controller function:

```
namespace MyApp\Controller;
require_once 'lib/result.php';
class Home extends \SlimController\SlimController
{
    public function dataAction()
    {
        $result = new Result;
    }
}
```

I get error in my PHP built-in server :`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyApp\Controller\Result' not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the `Result` class in the current namespace you could do

```
$result = new \Result();
```

or with

```
use Result;
```

after the namespace